# "Pros" and "Cons" Separately

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice

I am writing a paper. I am wondering can I use "Pros" and "Cons" as the title of two subsections separately? In other words, is it acceptable to use "pros" and "cons" separately no in the phrase of "pros and cons
"?

Note that, I know that I can use other choices such as "Strengths" and "Weaknesses" or any other pair. However, my question is on the "pros" and "cons" here and the possibility of writing them separately, not on the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, this structure is fine. It's a little simplistic. because things in the real world don't generally break down so nicely, and you lose opportunities to compare and contrast, but for certain kinds of work it works well enough.

However, using the terms 'Pros' and 'Cons' as section headers is poor form. these two terms are colloquialisms, and you should really avoid colloquial speech if you want the paper to be taken seriously. I'd suggest using complete and descriptive phrases: e.g., "Arguments in Favor of [...X...]" and "Arguments Against [...X...]".